# Python - nombres de grupos. Alternativa a unique

Tags: python

Existe alguna forma de extraer los elementos en los cuales se han hecho las agrupaciones?

```
 statistics_app = query.groupby('party').count()
```

La respuesta que obtengo es:

```
           Total_Approve  Total_Disapprove
party                                 
D                519               514
I                487               485
R                519               514
all              670               670
```

Quiero quedarme con los valores: 'D','I','R' Y 'all' pero la instrucción da error [KeyError: 'party'] ya que 'party' no es una columna

```
values = statistics_app['party']
```

Sólo se me ocurre obtenerla de la variable `query` mediante la función `unique()`.
Hay alguna otra forma?

Gracias.

Comment: No es una columna, es el índice. Intenta con `statistics_app.index`

Comment: @abulafia si mas no me equivico pandas acepta tanco `df[index]` como `df.index`, o no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podría asumir que '*query*' es un objeto tipo dataframe, si es así, solo tienes que utilizar `reset_index()`

```py
statistics_app = query.groupby('party').count().reset_index()
```

así ya puedes utilizar el acceso a los valores.

```py
values = statistics_app['party']
```

Debes tomar en cuenta el número de registros, resulta mas óptimo utilizar `unique()` que `groupby`, ej.

```py
# %timeit `unique()`
573 µs ± 7.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# %timeit `groupby()`
5.73 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```